# Website to check if laptop/GPU is certified for CentOS/RedHat Linux?

Tags: laptop, centos, gpu, redhat-enterprise-linux, centos-7

Is there a website where I can check if a laptop, or a graphic card, is certified for a certain version of CentOS/RedHat Linux?

E.g.,

1. Is an HP Envy x360 2-in-1 Laptop certified for CentOS 7.8?
2. Is an Intel Iris Plus GPU certified for RHEL 7.8?

### Edit 1

In [Red Hat Ecosystem Catalog](https://catalog.redhat.com/), these are all the certified Intel components: five in total -
[image: Components compatability]
These are all the certified HP Workstations: eighteen in total -
[image]

### Edit 2

The [Supported Hardware](https://www.linuxjournal.com/supportedhardware) site is also quite lean, and quite outdated, as it seems to have been last updated in 2007.

Comment: The close votes for this question are unwarranted.  This does not qualify as " product, service, or learning material recommendations."

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comments to my original answer, I am modifying my answer.  The OP was confusing the terms "Certified" and "compatible," Which are two completely different things.

This [website](https://www.linuxjournal.com/supportedhardware) links to the [Linux Hardware Compatibility HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Hardware-HOWTO/), which is what you are asking for, as well as other useful guides.

---

Below is my original answer, which no longer applies:

The website you are looking for is their [Red Hat Ecosystem Catalog](https://catalog.redhat.com/).  This site allows you to search for certified workstations (laptops are included), certified hardware components, and much more.

Comment: Thanks, @Keltari. Alas, I did search that site, but could find only servers and workstations, but neither laptops that I could recognise nor components.

Comment: @boardrider Look again, as this is ***EXACTLY*** what you are looking for.  Maybe you went to the wrong place?  Click the link in my answer.  Click "Explore hardware"  You are presented 3 options: Certified servers, workstations, and components.  The last 2 are what you are looking for.  Lets start by clicking "Explore workstations."  You are presented with a search page.  The left is search terms: Provider (Dell, Acer, etc), Version (what version of RHEL) and architecture (x86, x86_64).  The default search results literally show 5 Lenovo laptops first.  The same goes for the components.

Comment: Ah, I've been to https://catalog.redhat.com/, @Keltari, but the picking there are so meagre (see `Edit 1` in the OP), I thought maybe someone would know of a more comprehensive Linux hardware compatibility database.

Comment: @boardrider OK, I see what the issue is.  You are confusing "certified" with "compatible."  These are two completely different terms.  I modified my answer with what you are looking for.  Generally speaking if you purchase a Lenovo laptop that is "certified" with Red Hat, that means if you find something that isnt compatible, or does not work as intended, Lenovo and/or Red Hat will make it work.

Answer (score -2):

If you are a RH client you can probably call them.

If not, most linux hardware support happens on the kernel and it's drivers. A Web Search for "<make> <model> linux" usually gets you the info you want. For example, this user [reporting](https://www.reddit.com/r/AMDLaptops/comments/h8ckuc/review_hp_envy_x360_ryzen_5_4500u_kubuntu_linux/) with the AMD version of your machine. You Could also try to search for individual components on the [kernel source repository](https://git.kernel.org/), which is mirrored on github, for example a [search for your GPU](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/search?q=iris%20intel&unscoped_q=iris%20intel&type=Code)

As for the GPU you have, Most integrated GPUs nowadays are both supported in kernel and have awful 3D performance all around. Meaning, you will get decent Video out with any integrated GPU for Desktop and Video playback. Forget gaming.

Comment: This doesnt answer the question being asked, nor is the information given relevant to the question.